# How to search for specific URLs in ".url" files?

Tags: powershell, url, shortcut-file, file-search

I have a directory `D:\DMS` with lots of subfolders. Within these subfolders there are plenty of "`.url`" files which include URLs like

```
http://mmtst399:8080/dms/objekt?page=index&mode=browser&oid=K60081800
http://zrtpwvap877/dms/download?doc=N59748000
```

In order later on to replace some of the URLs I would like to search for such URLs by PowerShell eg. find a all URLs that start with `http://mmtst399:8080/` or find all URLs that contain `K60081800`
or find all URLs that start with `http://zrtpwvap877/dms/`.

That seems to be difficult to search for such URL within `.url` files. I tried already many different PowerShell sample scripts with like and so on, but finally it often shows "No results, No files found" even that I know that there are `.url` files in sub folder which contain such URLs. Of course it will be difficult to replace URLs in such files if PowerShell cannot even find that `.url` files.

I would like to search for such URLs in `.url` files, a txt log with paths of the found results. I guess searching such URL is difficult because some contain `=` and `?` and other characters.

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem` you can do something like `"K60081800","http://mmtst399:8080/","http://zrtpwvap877/dms/" | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Path D:\DMS -Recurse -Filter *.url | ForEach-Object {if((Get-Content $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) | Select-String -Pattern $_){$_ | Format-List FullName > D:\DMS\log.txt}}}` try that and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to match the URL parts of interest:

```bash
# The literal URL parts to find, either prefixes or substrings.
$urlParts = 'http://mmtst399:8080/', 'K60081800', 'http://zrtpwvap877/dms/'

# Formulate a regex that matches any of the above URL parts.
# The URL lines inside *.url files start with "URL="
$regex = '^URL=({0})' -f (
  $urlParts.ForEach({ 
    $escaped = [regex]::Escape($_) # Escape for literal matching
    if ($escaped -match '^https?:') { $escaped } 
    else                            { '.*' + $escaped } # Match anywhere in the URL
  }) -join '|'
)

# Search all *.url files in the subtree of D:\DMS for the URL parts
# and output the full paths of matching files.
# -Force ensures inclusion of *hidden* files too.
# Outputs to the screen; append e.g. > log.txt to save to a file.
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse D:\DMS -Filter *.url | 
  Select-String -Pattern $regex -List | 
  ForEach-Object Path
```

Note:

- The `URL=` entry of a `.url` file is permitted to contain URLs *without a protocol specifier* (e.g. `example.org` instead of `https://example.org`), which is why the regex for partial matching employed starts with `.*` (meaning any run of characters including possibly *none*).

Comment: Hi, I tried to find urls with D60081800 at the end but there it did not find anything even it is there in a subfolder

Comment: @MatthiasPuchta: It _should_ find it, but without detailed repro information we can't help you. Therefore, I suggest creating a _new_ question focused just on your remaining problem: reference this solution and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates a specific case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Now it works, i did something wrong with the path. The main idea with finding URLs in  thousands .url files is to replace "a part of a URL" in many files due to a server name change eg. find $urlParts = 'http://fhap299/dms/'   replace with http://fhal358:8080/dms/    and leave the rest of the URL as it is.

Comment: Now i found out when the PowerShell script does ---not---- work! Example here.....
I have a URL file in that path 
'code' "D:\DMS\7997\fa208496-0510-4461-a616-8c35f094a197\1.0001.url" and the URL is:  

'code' [link] http://fhp348:8080/dms/object?page=index&mode=browser&oid=D59770800

Now I enter in the beginning of the script a part the url but it does not find anything

'code' $urlParts = 'http://fhp348:8080/dms/'

No result, even that the file is there.

Comment: @MatthiasPuchta: Replace `'.+'` with `'.*'` - please see the updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try replacing that. It seems to be a tricky thing just to find some content :)

Comment: I guess it only works when I search for anything like D60081800 or similar simple things in such URL but when I add a URL http https and maybe eben with : in it then it will not work. I will try to post an answer with an image to show that it does not find anything even it is there

Comment: I place a new answer which shows an image where it ends with no result @mklement0
but maybe even such power shell search has it´s limitations

Comment: @MatthiasPuchta, please don't use _answer_ posts for follow-up _questions_ - ask a _new_ question instead, as recommended in my first comment above. A potential pitfall is that `Get-ChildItem` doesn't include _hidden_ files by default; add `-Force` to include them (I've updated the answer). The screenshot you're showing has the crucial part blurred out (the value of `$urlParts`).

Comment: I posted a new question. PowerShell, search for specific URL parts in .url files
The -Force thing did not bring any result. I did not hide anything in the new question