# PowerShell, search for specific URL parts in .url files

Tags: powershell, url, shortcut-file, file-search

Building on the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887069/45375), I tried this to find all `.url` files which include `http://kfhntwvap347`, but I also tried `http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/` in `$urlParts` knowing that there is such a `.url` file, but it always shows no results.

The intent is to find such URL and then to replace it.

```
# The literal URL parts to find, either prefixes or substrings.
$urlParts = 'http://kfhntwvap347'

$regex = '^URL=({0})' -f (
  $urlParts.ForEach({ 
    $escaped = [regex]::Escape($_) # Escape for literal matching, if needed.
    if ($escaped -match '^https?:') { $escaped } 
    else                            { '.*' + $escaped } # match anywhere in the URL
  }) -join '|'
)

# Search all *.url files in the subtree of D:\waveprod\DMS for the URL parts
# and output the full paths of matching files.
# Outputs to the screen and saves to a file.

$foundPaths = Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse D:\waveprod\DMS -Filter *.url | 
  Select-String -Pattern $regex -List | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $path = $_.Path
    Write-Output $path
    $path
  }

# Display a message based on whether results were found or not
if ($foundPaths.Count -gt 0) {
  Write-Host "Results found!"
} else {
  Write-Host "No results found."
}

# Save the found paths to a text file in D:\powershell\
$foundPaths | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\powershell\found_paths.txt'
```

[image]

I would expect that it finds such files but I tried many variations without success.

Comment: With `$urlParts = 'http://kfhntwvap347'`, the code _does_ match a `.url` file with the content shown in your screenshot in my tests. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: just checked it again, it is PSVersion 5.1.143 Desktop from PowerShell. Strange that it does not find anything

Comment: Like mklement0, I also tested your code and successfully found the URL file, so I don't have a solution but wanted to point out a couple minor improvements to your code. In your regex `if` statement, you're checking if it matches `^http?:'`. This regex matches either `http:` or `htt:`. I'm assuming what you want is `^https?:`, which matches `http:` or `https:`. Also in your `ForEach` loop you output the `$path` twice and also assigning `$_.path` to `$path` is unnecessary, just use this: `ForEach-Object { $_.path }`

Comment: Good catch, @jeremywat, and good points. I've fixed the `^http?:` part to avoid confusion: It was simply a copy-paste error from the linked answer.

Comment: @MatthiasPuchta: The following regex101.com page demonstrates that the regex that the code constructs does work against the `.url` file content shown in your answer: https://regex101.com/r/EpRKq7/1 If it doesn't work with your actual file, there are only two explanations I can think of: (a) Your file uses a character encoding PowerShell doesn't recognize (unlikely) or (b) your file contains hidden control characters.

Comment: @iRon: That is good advice in general, but wouldn't really help here (except perhaps to use `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut("d:\path\to\some.url").TargetPath` to more robustly extract the URL string). The linked post (to which this question is a follow-up) makes the use case clearer: matching one of multiple arbitrary URL prefixes and substrings, for which _text_ processing  is the right approach, and regexes allow for the most concise implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I find using `type casting` (if available) will help when working with some type of complex objects.

```
C:\> [uri]'http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/'


AbsolutePath   : /consense/
AbsoluteUri    : http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/
LocalPath      : /consense/
Authority      : kfhntwvap347:8080
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : False
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /consense/
Segments       : {/, consense/}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : kfhntwvap347
Port           : 8080
Query          :
Fragment       :
Scheme         : http
OriginalString : http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/
DnsSafeHost    : kfhntwvap347
IdnHost        : kfhntwvap347
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :
```

So by comparing the property `Authority` with `Host` (in this case filtering), you can easily tell if the URL-file needs to be handled.

```
[uri]'http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/',
[uri]'http://kfhntwvap347/consense/' |
  where {$_.Host -ne $_.Authority} |
    select AbsoluteUri

AbsoluteUri
-----------
http://kfhntwvap347:8080/consense/
```

In this case we also need a good way to handle ini-files. `PsIni` from `PSGallery` is a good bet.

```
Install-Module PsIni

Get-ChildItem .\*.url | select Name,
  @{ l = 'URI'; e = {[uri](Get-IniContent $_).InternetShortcut.Url} } |
    where {$_.URI.Host -ne $_.URI.Authority}
```

Edit: I didn't notice the property `IsDefaultPort` before which makes to selection even easier.